# Make stage draggable, but keep a specific shape always in the same relative position (KineticJS)

Tags: html, html5-canvas, draggable, kineticjs

does anybody know, how to drag the stage "behind" a certain shape or shape-group, so the shape doesn't get dragged around with all the other items on the stage and of course, the stage itself?

In my example I have a stage with many items outside of the visible part of the`<canvas>`-tag which can only be reached by dragging the stage to the left/right, but one of the shapes should be always on position `(0, 0)` of the `<canvas>`-element and shouldn't change its position while the stage is dragged.

I couldn't find a way to do this yet, so I would be very glad if anyone knows a way to get this working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the one shape left at (0,0) of the canvas is always the same shape and never changes, you can add all other elements to a group excluding the shape that is positioned at (0,0) and drag the group instead of dragging the stage.

If you must drag the stage, then you'll have to calculate the distance of x that the mouse has moved while dragging, and apply that to the position of the shape at (0,0).

Comment: Oh sorry, I forgot to mention, that there are several layers, the other elements are divided into, which makes grouping impossible (only groups and shapes can be grouped). Could you please explain the approach with the recalculation of the coordinates according to the changed mouse position a little bit more detailed? Thanks :)

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/projeqht/x89hw/

Use stage.getX() on event stage 'dragmove' to find the dx (distance of x) that the stage has moved. Then, subtract dx from the rectangle's X position to keep the rectangle's position static while the stage X is moving. Note that I restricted the stage's drag bounds to only the X axis.

Comment: Thanks for you work. I'll give it a try in the upcoming days. In the jsfiddle it is working flawlessly, but my code seems always to have its own rules. One last thing: this code doesn't work during tweens, does it? Because in my case, you give the stage a little push and tweens do the remaining work (for smooth easings)...

Comment: Regarding your one last thing: no, currently it wouldn't work during tweens since dx is only calculated from stage.on('dragmove') which is a mouse/tap event. I haven't used tweens yet but you can probably  calculate dx (stage.getX()) in a callback function for the tween (while the tween is executing) hopefully and calculate dx there as well! If you are able to calculate dx while tweening, you can apply the dx to the rectangle on stage dragmove and while tweening. Good luck!

Comment: do you have any idea how to get dx during a tween, because I'm currently moving the "static" shape with a tween, that has the same parameters as the one I'm using to move the stage, in the contrary direction, wich also works, but causes a little "shiver" during the transition. So I would guess, that recalculating the x from dx (which should be returned from the tween) allows me to get rid of this "shivering".

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/projeqht/FRRjN/ Is the X of your tween always static? If so this would work... Unfortunately I'm not sure of a way to grab the X value of a tween so that the counterTween dx is dynamic.. See my comments in the jsfiddle. Hope this helps!

Comment: thanks for your answer. Currently I'm doing exactly the same, but as you can probably see, the tweens aren't 100% synchronous, which causes slight differences in the movement instead of keeping the rectangle completely steady. Thats why I thought of recalculating the rectangles x-value "manually" (`rect.setX(dx)`), like I'm doing it on `dragmove`, to get rid of these small differences. To do that, I would need the x-value of the stage wich gets updated in the tween. Do you have any idea how to get that updated x-value?

Comment: Hmm I have seen the tweens act slightly shakey but it doesn't seem to happen all the time so not sure about that. And no I'm not exactly sure how to get that updated x-value, sorry. Do you have to use a tween? Maybe Custom animations would work? http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/kineticjs/html5-canvas-kineticjs-animation-tutorial/ and http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/kineticjs/html5-canvas-kineticjs-animate-position-tutorial/ and also http://kineticjs.com/docs/Kinetic.Animation.html Looks like you might be able to calculate dx per frame of an animation whereas you can't in tweens?

Comment: Hi @projeqht thanks for your help. I found out how to solve my problem simply by adding an eventlistener to the `xChange` property, wich allows me to use your `var dx = stage.getX();  rect.setX(-dx)` calculation with the updated x-value of the stage. Thanks again for helping me to solve this problem :)

Comment: Awesome man! Glad to hear it worked out and you found your solution! :D Good luck with the rest!